# Exsistence of weak solutions of an Inhomogeneous system Partial Diferential Ecuation with boundary Dirichlet Conditions.

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Let $\lambda_{i}$ be the i-th eigenvalue of the Laplace operator in $\Omega$ with Dirichlet boundary conditions.
Prove that for all $\lambda\in[0,\lambda_{1})$ the system (where $\lambda_{1}$ is the first eigenvalue associated to the lapalace operator.):
$$\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  -\Delta u=\lambda u+1 \hspace{.4cm} \mbox{     in  } \Omega,\\
  u=0 \hspace{.4cm} \mbox{     in  } \partial\Omega.
 \end{array}
\right.$$
has a weak solution $u_{\lambda}\in H^{0}_{1}(\Omega)$

P.D. I know that to prove the existence of the weak solution I have to use Lax-Miligram. Though I am not sure how to proceed.
One of the ideas that I have is to use this inequality
$$||u||_{H^2(U)}\leq C(||u||_{L^{2}(\Omega)}+||f||_{L^{2}(\Omega)})$$
where $u\subset H^{2}_{Loc}(\Omega)$ is a weak solution, $U\subset\subset\Omega$ and $C\geq0$ which does not depends on $u$. 
Also, I had the idea that by doing an asymptotic analysis of the eigenvalues in another norm like $L^2$ I can figure something out about this problem, but that is only an idea and I really don't think that the latter makes sense.
Also at one point, I considered the Fredholm alternative to trying to prove the existence of the weak solution, but I didn't come to anything useful. Besides this I am lost, any comment or help would be really appreciated.  :)

Comment: You need the variational characterization of $\lambda_1$, i.e. $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}^2 \ge \lambda_1 \|u\|_{L^2}^2$.

Comment: And how could I use that? I have also stumbled with that characterization in my notes, but I can't get a good idea of how to use it. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Lax Milgram - the resulting bilinera form will be coercive due to this estimate

Comment: Yes, I found out a few hours ago, ill post the answer in a few days. Thank you very much:)